# Combining Searchlogic named scopes with OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchlogic

Is something like this possible?

```
Product.price_greater_than(10000).or_tags_name_equals('luxury')
```

The wiki doesn't help much on this...

I saw in the wiki:

```
  User.id_or_age_lt_or_username_or_first_name_begins_with(10)
  => "id < 10 OR age < 10 OR username LIKE 'ben%' OR first_name like'ben%'"
```

I really don't get that, how in the world did "ben" comes up??? could anyone help please?

Comment: How about testing it in `./script/console`? .)

Comment: do you know anything that work?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it was a typo. This should work:

```
User.id_or_age_lt_or_username_or_first_name_begins_with([10, "ben"])
```